# Corrupt uploaded files with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo, upload

I need to upload and download files with php/mysql in my own little project.

The files are uploaded via form using POST and processed in the following way:

```
<?
$passName1 = $_FILES['passport1']['name'];
$tmpName1  = $_FILES['passport1']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize1 = $_FILES['passport1']['size'];
$fileType1 = $_FILES['passport1']['type'];
$fp1      = fopen($tmpName1, 'r');
$pass_1_content = fread($fp1, filesize($tmpName1));
fclose($fp1);
?>
```

Then I upload them using this function:

```
$passport1id = insert_user_file ($db, $passName1, $fileType1, $fileSize1, $pass_1_content);

function insert_user_file ($db, $name, $type, $size, $content) {
        try {
            echo "<br>start insert file $name";
            $insertfile = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['server'].";dbname=".$db['db'], $db['mysql_login'], $db['mysql_pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $insertfile->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // prepare sql and bind parameters
            $stmt=$insertfile->prepare ("INSERT INTO files (name, size, type, content, created) VALUES (:name, :size, :type, :content, NOW())");

            $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":size", $size);
            $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type);
            $stmt->bindParam(":content", $content);
            $stmt->execute();

            $file_id = $insertfile->lastInsertId();
            return $file_id;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'error: '. $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The presence of addslashes() to name/content of the file does not seem to make any difference at all.
Seems to work fine however when I get the file back with the function below, it appears to be corrupt:

```
get_file ($db, $_GET['id']);

function get_file ($db, $fileid){
        try {
            $get_file = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['server'].";dbname=".$db['db'], $db['mysql_login'], $db['mysql_pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
            $get_file->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $file = $get_file->prepare("SELECT * FROM files where fileid=:fileid");
            $file->bindParam(":fileid", $fileid);
            $file->execute();
            $file_data = $file->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header("Content-length: {$file_data['size']}");
            header("Content-type: {$file_data['type']}");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file_data['name']}");
            echo $file_data['content'];
            exit;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            //echo 'error: '. $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `addslashes()` is utterly useless. You're using a prepared statement with placeholders. The DB will already (internally) do any necessary escaping to keep the data safe. All you're doing is basically a DOUBLE-encoding, so yes, the data is corrupted, because you're adding a bunch of backslashes which do not exist in the original data, and they're NOT removed by the DB.

Comment: `$pass_1_content = addslashes($pass_1_content);` You did the corrupting all by yourself

Comment: and note that if that file you're reading is "large", you risk killing your script with out-of-memory errors. PHP uses "pass-by-value", so by reading the file outside if your db function, and then passing it into the function, you're DOUBLING  the ram requirement, because two copies of that file will exist in memory.

Comment: @MarcB I have suspected and ruled out this earlier. If this line is removed, nothing gets changed, file is still corrupt.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Does not seem to be the case

Comment: then open the corrupted version into a text/hex editor, and compare it against the original. Make sure youa ctually received the exact same bytes. maybe you've got php warnings in there, because something glitched in the download script.

Comment: @MarcB I will have to do it this way im afraid. Warnings are enabled, there is just one, related to unspecified index in an unrelated part of the code

Comment: there you go. if you have php outputting anything OTHER than the file's contents, that "other" stuff becomes PART of the downloaded file, and there's your corruption.

Comment: @MarcB PHP uses copy-on-write, so it doesn't double the memory unless you modify the original array. Since strings are immutable, they never need to be copied.

Comment: still, not a good idea to load arbitrary files into memory.

Comment: @MarcB It's not outputting anything other than that file. Anyway i have downloaded the file BLOB from DB, its still corrupted. Gonna compare them in text editor

Comment: @MarcB There is clearly difference at the very beginning of the hex. Needless to say, md5 checksums are different. Any advice?

Comment: what's the type of the field you're storing this in? if it's not `blob` (or variants), then it's subject to character set translation rules, and some random binary garbage in the raw data MAY look like a unicode character and get translated into something else on retrieval (e.g. win1252 collation on the field, utf8 on the connection to php).

Comment: @MarcB I do use mediumblob. The encoding is utf8-Default collation. Would you rather suggest using binary or varbinary?

Comment: @MarcB Well, I didnt change code much, but now, downloading the files directly from DB blob shows that files are not corrupt, they get corrupt on the browser output stage. Each file starts with  . . . .  or in hex: 09 09 09 09.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue! Stupid me, I should have put the whole code here, because it resulted into confusion!

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'functions.php';

    /*
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) OR $_SESSION['logged'] == false){
        header ("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    */

    //somecode here
    //echo "logged in ok";
    get_file ($db, $_GET['id']);


?>
```

The culprit is in the line 2 ob_start(); which overrode e warnings like:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /sata2/home/users//functions.php:289) in /sata2/home/users//functions.php on line 130
```

The line 289 had several whitespaces after `?>   //some spaces were here`

This is a very silly mistake. Thank a lot to @MarcB for hinting that there might have been warnings I could miss. Never leave whitespaces after `?>`

Comment: Good catch. And as a general rule, you DON'T need a final/closing `?>` in PHP scripts. it's only necessary if there's other non-PHP content that needs outputting (which, it turns out, you had).